# Coin Flip - Expectation if allowed to reflip all or none after first flipping

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I have 4 coins, and you get $1 for each tail that you flip.

Based on this, the expectation would be E(X) = 4(1/2) = 2

Now, if after the first flipping of coins (4 flips), you have the opportunity to reflip all or none of them. What is the expected gain?

From my understanding, if we let X = number of tails flipped, we get the following:

P(X <= 1) = 5/16

P(X > 1) = 11/16

X follows a binomial(4, 1/2) distribution.

In this case, it only makes sense for the player to reflip if they got 1 or less tails. What would the expectation be then?

Comment: Well, what are your thoughts?

Comment: E(total) = P(X<=1)(2) + P(X>1)(3). I'm not too sure about the second term, but I based it off of the fact that the player must have gotten 2, 3, or 4 tails.

Comment: As a hint:  it simplifies the computation a little if you note that rolling the second time you can assume you get the expected value.  If that's not clear to you, then just write out all the cases.  After all, there aren't very many cases here.

Comment: I'm a little confused. In here: E(total) = P(X<=1)(2) + P(X>1)(3), I did make that assumption that the expected value is 2 if flipping the second time (if X <= 1). If I flipped more than 1 tails (2 or more), I assume that I've gotten 2, 3, or 4 tails. I suppose I could find the expectation for the second part by first finding the probability of getting 2, 3, or 4 tails.

Comment: There are only $5$ possible outcomes here.  if you toss $0$ Tails then your expected payout is $2$.  Same if you toss $1$ tail or $2$ tails.  If you toss $3$ you get $3$ and if you toss $4$ you get $4$.  Now just compute the probabilities of each outcome and weight accordingly.

Comment: Oops, I think I had a major brain fart. My end result is 38/16, which is just E(total) = P(X<=1)(2) + P(X=2)(2) + P(X=3)(3) + P(X=4)(4)

Comment: Yep, I agree with that.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!